# Telerik KendoUI Angular line chart not reflecting dashType in legend

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I've got a chart in which I'm setting the dashType property for different series but the legend isn't reflecting the setting and is showing everything as a solid line. How do you get the legend to reflect this setting? I'm using Angular 7 with the latest build of the chart components. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This behavior isn't supported out-of-the-box but can be added.
You can see a question about it and the reply on Telerik's forums [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/dash-dot-solid-chart-legend-markers).

The suggested solution is to use the `[item]` attribute of the `kendo-chart-legend` component.

**See the following example usage:**

Place this in your component's template inside the `Kendo Chart component:

```
<kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal" [item]="{ visual: legendItemVisual }">
</kendo-chart-legend>
```

Place this in your component's code:

```
public legendItemVisual = (args: any) => {
    const path = new Path({ stroke: { color: args.series.color, dashType: args.series.dashType, width: 2}})
        .moveTo(0, 0).lineTo(25);
    const text = new Text(args.series.name);
    const layout = new Layout(new Rect([0, 0], [Number.MAX_VALUE, 0]), {
        alignItems: "center",
        cursor: 'pointer',
        spacing: 5
    });

    layout.append(path, text);
    layout.reflow();

    return layout;
}
```

Comment: Nice one Shai! It looks like this code snippet needs an update, though, as the presented code has a runtime error.

Update the text line to `const text = new Text(args.series.name, [0, 0]);` and you should be all set!

Comment: Thanks! :)
Unfortunately, for some reason, the demo in the link I provided doesn't load, so I can't test this... Anyway, if anyone comes across this question, uses my answer and gets a runtime error, with your comment he has the solution for that as well.
I'll try to get the demo running to test this when I get a chance.